# Handling Errors in Spring integration Poller

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm using `FtpStreamingMessageSource` in combination with poller with following config (`@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel", poller = @Poller("pollerMetadata"))`):

```
@Bean
    public PollerMetadata pollerMetadata(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
        trigger.setFixedRate(true);

        MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource source = new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource();
        source.setTransactionAttribute(new DefaultTransactionAttribute());
        TransactionInterceptor interceptor = new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, source);

        PollerMetadata metadata = new PollerMetadata();
        metadata.setTrigger(trigger);
        metadata.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(synchronizationFactory());
        metadata.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(interceptor));
        return metadata;
    }
```

It was working OK, until today I had a DB problem and an exception `The last packet sent successfully to the server was 30,079 milliseconds ago.` and `(ERROR): LoggingHandler org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is
closed`.

Somehow, poller stopped working after this, even though HikariCP managed to recover from exception after a while. Seems like a thread that was doing polling job was terminated.

Any idea how to make thread recover and continue with processing? After I restarted application, everything was back to normal.

**UPDATE**

this is the last exception I got before poller stopped working

```
2019-03-06 14:34:45 (ERROR): LoggingHandler org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is
closed
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:290)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:853)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:830)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:503)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:285)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:489)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.rollback(Unknown Source)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:370)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:287)
        ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "termination" of a polling thread; polling uses a `TaskScheduler` and when the poll completes (whether an exception occurred or not) the thread is returned to the pool, ready for the next poll.

It's probably too late now (if you restarted your app) but if it happens again take a thread dump; most likely the poller thread is "stuck" somewhere in user (or DB) code.

Comment: Yes, I just checked the code, it seems it should not be killed. I assume it is somewhere in my app code then... Maybe this `StripedKeyLockManager` from jkeylockmanager had something to do with it.